# Gymming and Martial arts at the same time

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, recommendation, strength, fitness

I am a member of a gym for 7 months and do strength based exercises 5-6 days a week (in the evening) along with 10-15 minutes of cardio. I have decided to join a mixed martial art facility near my area. The instructor(s) will teach kick boxing for two consecutive days followed by grappling moves for two consecutive days. There are no gap between lessons, and they are held in the mornings.

Is it advisable to go to the gym at evening after training in the morning? If yes, what should be the minimal cool off/rest period between gym and MMA training classes?

Comment: This practice is not really that novel.  Bruce Lee blended western style weight training with Chinese style martial arts training.  It was controversial at the time, but obviously very effective.  Goju ryu and various Okinawan systems of karate, and Vietnamese kung fu specifically incorporate forms of weight training.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the same situation. For the past 6 months I've been hitting the gym for 5-6 days a week. My schedule looks like this:

Mo: chest/shoulders
Tu: arms/back
We: legs/cardio
Tu: same as Mo
Fr: same as Tu
Sa: same as We

Every Tuesday and Friday evening I go to Wing Chun: a lesson is 2 hours, the first 25 minutes are hardcore cardio.

My goals are working on my fysiek and getting very good at WC. From the moment I included 2 days a week of Wing Chun in my weekly training schedule, my fysiek got a big BIG boost. I got a better condition, and even better; I lost extra body fat with as result that I am very pleased with my current fysiek. I'm in good shape and look much leaner.

I have absolutely no problem with over-training whatsoever. I would almost say that the 2 days of WC every week loosens up my muscles. I hope my answers helped.